# How can I deploy Language Packs to Windows 7 Enterprise domain clients using WSUS?

Tags: windows-7, wsus, language-packs

Following on from a previous question (see [Using Group Policy to set Domain client language / regionalization](https://serverfault.com/questions/299172/using-group-policy-to-set-domain-client-language-regionalization)) I'm wondering how I can deploy Windows 7 Language packs to some Windows 7 Enterprise workstations using WSUS?

My workstations are all kiosk-like computers that need to default to a given language depending on what country-specific OU they're in on the AD. I can set up GPOs to force that language to be used, but this does nothing if that specific language pack isn't installed. All of the workstations have been deployed with an English UK build, so default to English UK as their language. If I use a specific workstation and run the Windows Update client and tell it to search Microsoft Update, I can see the various language packs available directly from Microsoft. However, looking around my WSUS server, the only language packs I can see are for Vista, with nothing for Windows 7. Looking around the Microsoft Update Catalog, I can't seem to find anything either.

Given that I have a set handful of languages I know I'm going to need, how best can I deploy these automatically using WSUS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't, according to this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813